# Android/Java Standard Package names are they protected

Tags: android, security, android-ndk, package

I need to make a reference to a builtin Android Java Class in NDK c++ code.

You can do it by 
cls_tm = (*env)->FindClass(env, "javax/crypto/Cipher");

I am worried someone can tamper with apk, extract the java code then create their own class with the package name javax.crypto.Cipher, and read all the sensitive data I am passing to it. I am new to Java and Android so I wanted to know if it is possible to create your own package with same name as built in packages like javax.crypto.Cipher?

Comment: Ordinarily components in an app which conflict with the names of platform components are discarded at install in favor of the platform versions.  It may be possible to override that behavior, but even if it's not, your app's compiled dalvik bytecode can be modified to refer instead to custom components with unique names, or the behavior of the VM it runs on can be altered, or the app can be installed on a device with a modified platform where the system versions of those packages have been subverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create classes with the same name.  However, they do not take the place of existing classes.

Every class is loaded by a class loader.  Class loaders form a hierarchy, with the "bootstrap" class loader at the very top.  The class loader that loads your app's classes is created by the Android app framework; it is a child of the "system" class loader, which is a child of the bootstrap loader.

When your app references a class, it asks its class loader to find it by name.  Each loader will either return a class that it defined, or ask its parent to find it.  (The default behavior is to ask the parent first, but an individual loader can override this.)

`javax.crypto.Cipher` is part of `core.jar`, which is loaded by the bootstrap class loader.  So unless your application's class loader decides to replace `Cipher` with its own version, you will get the system version.

(The JNI `FindClass` call is actually a bit strange.  Depending on where you are when you call it, it can actually end up in the system class loader rather than your app's loader.  See [this section in JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass) for an explanation.)

Suppose you really did want to replace `Cipher`.  You can provide your own version, and your app code will happily use it.  However, when you try to pass it to some other code in `core.jar`, your app will fail.  This is because classes loaded in the VM aren't unique by name, but rather by the combination of name and class loader.  So you can't pass a `Cipher+MyAppLoader` into something that expects a `Cipher+bootstrap`.

In any event, if somebody modified your APK, they would have to re-sign it; since they don't have your private key, it wouldn't look like an app that came from you.

If somebody modified a device and replaced the system `Cipher` with their own version, they can do whatever they want.

Comment: thanks, I don't why know Google don't introduce a native version of LVL checking, I guess they see piracy as a favourable feature